# I want to connect an IP camera to a page made through HTML, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing an interface through what is html, css and javascript, more than anything for the ease of the wifi network, I am also dealing with what is the MQTT protocol, but the problem is that I need communication with a camera

When investigating I was able to notice that the best option is an IP camera, but the problem is that there are almost no examples with this type of cameras since they normally come with their application and sometimes without some type of IP to display on this type of pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 and JavaScript.

1. Get the IP Camera's Video Stream URL (You'll need to check your camera's documentation or settings to obtain this URL)
2. HTML5 Video Element: You can use the HTML5  tag to display the video stream on your web page. E.G:

```
<video id="camera-stream" controls autoplay></video>
```

3. You'll need to use JavaScript to set the src attribute of the  element to the URL of your IP camera's video stream. E.G:

```
<script>
  const videoElement = document.getElementById('camera-stream');
  const cameraStreamURL = 'YOUR_CAMERA_STREAM_URL_HERE';

  videoElement.src = cameraStreamURL;
</script>
```

P.D: You might encounter cross-origin issues when trying to access the camera stream from a different domain. In such cases, you may need to configure CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) on the IP camera or use a proxy server.

Comment: HTML video tag doesn't support IP camera stream